# How to fetch the all the post data from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I m using FB API and few issues that i want to discuss,

1) Facebook API accurately pulls the number of comments for e.g 12, but when it comes to pulling the comments for e.g. 'Intelligently written, I agree with you' it may just pull out 10 out of those 12 total comments, is it possible to pull out those 12 comments accurately (Same for the no. of post also and content of the post).

2) The pulling of feed is limited to a limited number of posts,  is it possible to pull retroactive feeds- for example setting the back dates for pulling the historical feed (or if there is another way of pulling out feed previous to the current date)

Thanks 
Digitech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull all the comments from a post (in this case 12) by fetching the path

```
/postID####/comments?limit=12
```

Likewise, you can fetch a larger number of posts from a feed by setting the limit and/or timeframe

`/me/feed?limit=50`

or

`/me/feed?limit=50&since=1351561400`

or

`/me/feed?limit=50&until=1352309353`

You can just set the limit to whatever you'd like and the time to either until or since a point in time (measured in Unix time).

You can play with all the options on the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).